# Can't execute cmd.exe /Q /C %c

Tags: python, windows, cmd, geany

I have set up Geany with Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 machine, but after setting the compile and execute commands, Geany complains that it can't execute cmd.exe. The console itself is working fine, it is however also not working in different IDEs (Sublime Text 2)

The particular error message is as follows (Russian):

> 22:06:59: Не могу выполнить команду "cmd.exe /Q /C %c": Неверно задано имя папки. Проверьте правильность пути в настройках.

which translates to:

> 22:06:59: Cannot execute command "cmd.exe /Q /C %c": Wrong folder name. Check correctness of path in settings.

I have added C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe in front of it and also tried setting %c in quotes: "%c", both it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

#### If `%c` is actually something interpreted by CMD

If `%c` itself is encapsulated by quotes (IDK what Sublime is doing), then you'll need to tell CMD to exclude them: `%~c`

Another thing to try is telling CMD to use the short path name (without quotes): `%~sc` (See `FOR /?` for details about substitution.)

#### See What's Happening with Process Monitor

A good fallback for (sub-)shell command debugging is to run [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiztJKmwNTMAhUn8IMKHSvtBQMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsysinternals%2Fprocessmonitor.aspx&usg=AFQjCNF6MDkkugPoCBWRXbwAO2hEwRrdaw&bvm=bv.121658157,d.amc) whenever Geany attempts to run a command. Find the process it spawned (or attempted to spawn) and look at the complete command-line. That might give you a better clue about what's going wrong.

Comment: cmd.exe \Q \C %~c and cmd.exe \Q \C %~sc with and without quotes arent working and returning the same error in geany. Any other things to try maybe?

Comment: `%c` gets expanded by Geany to the path of the run script that it creates in the temporary directory. See [terminal emulators](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#terminal-emulators). The default on Windows is `cmd.exe /Q /C %c`. Maybe you have an incorrect working directory defined for the build command. If empty it defaults to the directory of the current document.